# VS Enterprise load test originating IP Address

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, load-testing

If I run a load test from VS enterprise using a single agent, will all the request come from a single IP Address, which effectively means a single user?

EDIT:
I cannot check the IIS logs, as the site is load balanced and access is controlled via  gateway - so the IIS logs all show the IP address of the gateway. So far I have not been able to find any logs for the gateway

Comment: There are many configuration options for many load balancers. You can probably find a way of distributing the load from one IO address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a load test from single agent, all request come from the single IP Address of that agent, unless you enable IP switching.

But it does **not** mean, it is a single user!!

There are as many parallel user sessions and connections open as you specify. (there can be hundreds of TCP connections open with different source ports from the agent)

Comment: my understanding of IIS is that if the request originate from the same IP Address and machine, IIS will queue the requests and treat them as the same user, rather than as individual users - is this correct?

Comment: no, that is absolutely *not* correct, not even close. Do you have access to the agent? you can check e.g. with netstat the open tcp connections. I

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> IP Switching used to configure IP switching, it allows **a test agent** to send requests to a server by using a **range of IP address**, this **simulates** calls that **come from different client** computers.
>
> To use the IP switching feature, the test agent service must be running as a user in the Administrators group for that agent computer.
>
> To verify that IP switching is working correctly, enable IIS logging on the web server and check the log file.
>
> 1. Open your load test and select a scenario
> 2. In the Properties window, set IP switching to True.
> 3. Right click the a section and select Manage Test Controller
> 4. Select an test agent and click Properties
> 5. Check Enable IP Switching and configure NIC, Base Address …
> 6. Right click your solution and select Add=> New Item, select Test Settings and add a new test Settings
> 7. Configure test setting with Remote execution
> 8. Select TEST menu=>Test Settings=>Select Test Settings file, then select that test setting file
> 9. Run your load test.

Answer is quoted from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32b82742-8b01-43d4-8feb-e6c75f601199/how-to-setup-ip-switching-with-agents-and-controller-in-vs-2015-enterprise-edit?forum=vsmantest).

Comment: apologies they are there now

Comment: @Alex Sorry, i don't think i understand what you mean with your edit. Are you saying that in the IIS logs, the ip-adresses are all the same? Maybe this is what you are looking for (for the IIS setup): https://campus.barracuda.com/product/webapplicationfirewall/doc/41106572/logging-actual-client-ip-address-in-the-iis-7-and-iis-7-5-server/

Comment: this is exactly my issue and this solution could solve it. The app is hosted on Azure so I am not sure if I will be able to install this module, but will have a look

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you want me to add / change anything in my answer i'll be happy to. You might want to enable **Application Insights** and use **Web server telemetry** and **NSG Flow Logging** in Azure, maybe that solves it straight away?